# How to properly code a TeX file, or at least avoid `badness 10000`

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, best-practices, badness

I'm coding a TeX file and although the .pdf is correctly rendered, I'm using "stone age" tools to code it. As some examples, I use `\\` to leave a line space between two paragraphs, or `\noindent` in every paragraph I start. Basically, I'm just using the basic TeX data I have to code a paper, but I'm sure there are things that can be replaced with much better and appropriate codes, since I get `badness 10000`. This is the console:

```
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--11
[1{C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Datos de programa/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/conf
ig/pdftex.map}]
Overfull \hbox (10.8009pt too wide) detected at line 49
\OML/cmm/m/it/14.4  [] \OT1/cmr/m/n/14.4 + 1 = [] [] \OML/cmm/m/it/14.4 x \OT1
/cmr/m/n/14.4 + [] [] \OML/cmm/m/it/14.4 x
[2]
Overfull \hbox (26.66542pt too wide) in alignment at lines 80--82
 [][][] []
[3]
Overfull \hbox (23.60692pt too wide) detected at line 90
\OML/cmm/m/it/14.4  [] \OMS/cmsy/m/n/14.4 ><C:/Archivos de programa/MiKTeX 2
.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb>
```

How could I clean up these errors, which I'm guessing are basic?

Comment: Given log shows that overful boxes occured in math equations. Check   your equations and use `multline` environment from `amsmath` package to typeset long eqs. `amsmath` also has many other environments for math materials.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Never use `\\` to add space between paragraphs. This simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

text\\    
text
\end{document}
```

produces the message

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--6
```

Besides clogging the console output and the .log file with warnings, using `\\\par` has real undesired effects when a page break occurs just after using this combination, as can be seeing using the following simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\vspace*{44\baselineskip}
test text\\

test text

\end{document}
```

An image of the top of the second page:

[image]

The second page contains a spurious blank line at the beginning and this certainly makes the layout ugly and inconsistent (Thanks to **David Carlisle** which mentioned this problem).

If you want to suppress indentation and increase the vertical separation between paragraphs, you have, at least, three options:

1. Set `\parindent` to `0pt` (to suppress indentation) and use `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip` to increase the vertical skip between paragraphs; an example:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

   \setlength\parindent{0pt}% globally suppress indentation

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[2]\medskip

   \lipsum[2]

   \end{document}
   ```

gives

[image]

2. Load the [parskip](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package. For example:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{parskip}
   \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[2]

   \lipsum[2]

   \end{document}
   ```

produces:

[image]

3. Use one of the [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) document clases and one of the options of the `parskip=` or `halfparskip=` family (see the documentation for details). An example:

   ```
   \documentclass[parskip=full+]{scrartcl}
   \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \lipsum[2]

   \lipsum[2]

   \end{document}
   ```

produces:

[image]

Just to explain why using `\\` followed by a blank line (or a `\par` command) produces the warning:

when TeX ends a paragraph, it inserts something like

```
\unskip \penalty10000 \hskip\parfillskip
```

doing `\\\par` will result in

```
\\ \unskip \penalty10000 \hskip\parfillskip
```

The `\unskip` has no effect since it finds no preceding glue, so `\\` is followed by a penalty and a glue which will disappear after the line break; however, TeX was already expecting an extra line but there is nothing to fill it with, so an underfull box results.

Comment: But does it actually *hurt* anything? Or does it just make the console output messier? (As opposed to the typeset output.)

Comment: @cfr I've seen (ugly) 300+ pages documents typeset using ` \\ ` followed by a blank line to leave additional vertical separation between (almost) all paragraphs. I haven't seen any catastrophic consequence of doing this, besides producing ugly results (both because that extra space is bad practice and because in some cases the user forgot to add ` \\ ` introducing inconsistencies in the document).

Comment: @cfr So, I've never seen any disastrous effect os uding that and I cannot think of any (besides what I mentioned above); however, I'll ask in chat to the TeX gurus to see if they know of any such effect.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to entirely avoid them when creating things like teaching materials (syllabi, handouts, assignments) where they seem hard to avoid. That is, I don't use `\\\` followed by a blank line to separate paragraphs but I do sometimes increase the spacing between paragraphs in other ways. In something like an article, it is different. But there seem a lot of things LaTeX doesn't like about course materials and handouts etc.

Comment: @cfr Today I asked David Carlisle in chat about possible undesired "real" side-effects of ` \\\par` and he mentioned problems with page breaks. I designed this little MWE which shows this real problem:  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\vspace*{44\baselineskip}
test text\\

test text

\end{document}`. As you can see, the second page has a spurious empty line at the beginning due to the `\\ `.

Comment: Thank you! That's helpful and I have occasionally seen that. (I think with my CV which uses all kinds of spacing nastiness to try to fit things together.) I guess what I'm not entirely clear about is what good alternatives look like...